# Magento 1.9 url_rewrite it doesn't work with query string

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to enter an url_rewrite entry but I have a problem with the get parameters of the source url, it is as if the application would not take them into account.

The problem is only in the url that have parameters get like in this case with "?mId=162": "pequeno-electrodomestico/climatizacion/ventiladores/-c-204_267_388.html?mId=162"

The code works and records the entry but only redirects correctly if I enter that registry from admin and save without changing anything. Without doing that back save does not redirect.

I have done it as follows:

```
$_urlrewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');
$_urlrewrite->setIsSystem(1);
$_urlrewrite->setIdPath('OSC_URL-category_' . $_category->getId() . '_mId=' . $osc_path[8]);
$_urlrewrite->setRequestPath("pequeno-electrodomestico/climatizacion/ventiladores/-c-204_267_388.html?mId=162");
$_urlrewrite->setTargetPath("peque-o-electrodomestico/frio-y-calor/ventiladores/s_p");
$_urlrewrite->setOptions('RP');
$_urlrewrite->save();
```

So it is supposed to work but does not redirect.

Do I need to do something else after save ()?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
       ->setIsSystem(0)
       ->setOptions('RP')
        ->setIdPath('OSC_URL-category_' . $_category->getId() . '_mId=' . $osc_path[8])
        ->setTargetPath('peque-o-electrodomestico/frio-y-calor/ventiladores/s_p')
        ->setRequestPath('pequeno-electrodomestico/climatizacion/ventiladores/-c-204_267_388.html?mId=162')
    ->save();
```

Comment: I've tried that way and it does the same, it doesn't redirect.
Could the parameters have something to do with the symbol '?'

Comment: What is use of mId?

Comment: I have the old url with this mId? for use it to filter products by manufacturer_id in current ecommerce platform but i need to do a 301 redirect to new url in new magento site.